# iterate through mongodb colllection in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am a beginner in pymongo and flask and I have a movies collection where a movie instance is like :

```py
movie = { "title": "Hobbit", "year": "2013", "plot": "some plot" }
```

I am trying to iterate through my whole movies collection to check if a movie I have submitted in a form exists inside the collection . The movie title and year have to be the same .
My code :

```py
movie_list = movies.find()
for i in movie_list:
    for t in i['title']:
         for y in i['year']:
             if request.form['movie'] == t and request.form['year'] == y:
                 print("found")
                 break
```

However, when I test the above code using the print statement it prints nothing even if the movie and year I have submitted exist in my mongodb collection. I would appreciate your help in guiding me to solve this simple task. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aim just to check the existence of your movie, it's better to do it like this:

```py
count = movies.count_documents({"title": request.form["movie"], "year": request.form["movie"]})
if count:
    print("found")
```

If you want to do it with a loop,

```py
movies = movies.find({"title": request.form["movie"], "year": request.form["movie"]})
for movie in movies:
    if movie["title"] = request.form["movie"] and movie["year"] = request.form["year"]:
        print("found")
```

Comment: I know but I would like to know how it would work with iteration